# WindowFunction cannot be applied using WindowStream.apply() function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm relatively new to using Apache Flink and Scala, and am just getting to grips with some of the basic functionality. I've hit a wall trying to implement a custom `WindowFunction`.

The problem is that when I try to implement a custom `WindowFunction` the IDE gives an error on the ".apply()" function

```
Cannot resolve symbol apply

Unspecified value parameters: foldFunction: (NotInferedR, Data.Fingerprint) => NotInferedR, windowFunction: (Tuple, TimeWindow, Iterable[NotInferedR], Collector[NotInferedR]) => Unit 
Unspecified value parameters: foldFunction: FoldFunction[Data.Fingerprint, NotInferedR], function: WindowFunction[NotInferedR, NotInferedR, Tuple, TimeWindow] 
Unspecified value parameters: function: WindowFunction[Data.Fingerprint, NotInferedR, Tuple, TimeWindow] 
Unspecified value parameters: windowFunction: (Tuple, TimeWindow, Iterable[Data.Fingerprint], Collector[NotInferedR]) => Unit 

Type mismatch, expected: (Tuple, TimeWindow, Iterable[Data.Fingerprint], Collector[NotInferedR]) => Unit, actual: DataTimeWindow.DataWindow 
Type mismatch, expected: WindowFunction[Data.Fingerprint, NotInferedR, Tuple, TimeWindow], actual: DataTimeWindow.DataWindow
```

This is my code:

```
val test = hashMap
      .keyBy("hash")
      .timeWindow(Time.minutes(1))
      .apply(new DataWindow())
```

And this is the `WindowFunction`:

```
class DataWindow extends WindowFunction[Data.Fingerprint, String, String, TimeWindow]  {

    override def apply(key: String,
                       window: TimeWindow,
                       input: Iterable[Fingerprint],
                       out: Collector[String]) {

      out.collect("helo")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the third type parameter of the `WindowFunction`, i.e., the type of the key. Because you declare the key in the `keyBy` method as String (`keyBy("hash")`), it is not possible to determine the type of the key at compile time. There are two options to resolve this:

1. Use a `KeySelector` function in `keyBy` to extract the key (something like `keyBy(x: FingerPrint => x.hash)`). The return type of the `KeySelector` function is known at compile time such that you can use a typed `WindowFunction`.
2. Change the type of the third type parameter of the `WindowFunction` to `Tuple`. `Tuple` is a generic holder for the keys extracted by `keyBy`. In your case it will be a `Tuple1` and the hash String can be accessed by `Tuple1.f0`.

Comment: hello @fabian,
I add `keyBy((x : Data.Fingerprint) => x.hash)` and  in my "DataWindow" class I change `String` to `Tuple1[String]` but I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you make both changes at the same time or tried both one after the other? If you change the `KeyExtractor` you should keep the key type as `String`.

Comment: I try both solution.

Comment: I fix this issue, I need to import `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.WindowFunction` not `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.WindowFunction`
Thanks @fabian to take some time on this issue.

Comment: Thank you FlinkNoob. @FabianHueske is there any way to give some other hint in the error or change the imports ? this is really confusing