# Flink apply function on timeWindow

Tags: java, json, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm currently doing a Flink project. The main idea of the project is to read a datastream of JSON's (network logs), correlate them, and generate a new JSON, which is a combination of different JSON's information.

At this moment, I'm able to read the JSON's, genereate a KeyedStream (based on the machine that generates the log), and then generate a window stream of 5 seconds.

The next step I want to perform is to use the apply function to the window and combine the information of each JSON. I'm a bit confused of how to do it.

The code I currently have is the following one:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String,JSONObject>> MetaAlert = events
                .flatMap(new JSONParser())
                .keyBy(0)
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .apply(new generateMetaAlert());




public static class generateMetaAlert implements WindowFunction<Tuple2<String,JSONObject>, Tuple2<String,JSONObject>, String, Window> {

        @Override
        public void apply(String arg0, Window arg1, Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> arg2,
                Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> arg3) throws Exception {


        }
```

The .apply(new generateMetaAlert()) part is complaining with the next error:

The method apply(WindowFunction,R,Tuple,TimeWindow>) in the type WindowedStream,Tuple,TimeWindow> is not applicable for the arguments (MetaAlertGenerator.generateMetaAlert)

Any other code structure proposal distinct that the one I made up?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47033981/probleme-with-apply-function-windowfunction-in-flink). Please check and close if the answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the `keyBy` function (without using an anonymous class) the type of the key in your custom `WindowFunction` (3rd field) should be `Tuple` because the compiler can not determine the type of your key. This code compiles with no errors (take into account that I tried to fill the blanks with dummy code):

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        DataStream<String> events = env.readTextFile("datastream.log");

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> MetaAlert
                = events
                .flatMap(new JSONParser())
                .keyBy(0)
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .apply(new GenerateMetaAlert());

    }

    public class JSONObject {
    }

    public class JSONParser implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> collector) throws Exception {

        }
    }

    public class GenerateMetaAlert implements WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple, TimeWindow> {
        @Override
        public void apply(Tuple key, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> collector) throws Exception {

        }
    }

}
```

But the most straightforward method is to use an anonymous class so you can keep the `String` type:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> MetaAlert
        = events
        .flatMap(new JSONParser())
        .keyBy(0)
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
        .apply(new WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple, TimeWindow>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(Tuple tuple, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> collector) throws Exception {
                // Your code here
            }
        });
```

Finally, if you want to keep the class, but you also want to keep the type of you key as it is, you can implement a `KeySelector`:

```
public class Test {

    public Test() {

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> MetaAlert
                = events
                .flatMap(new JSONParser())
                .keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<String,JSONObject>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String getKey(Tuple2<String, JSONObject> json) throws Exception {
                        return json.f0;
                    }
                })
                .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .apply(new GenerateMetaAlert());
    }

    public class GenerateMetaAlert implements WindowFunction<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, Tuple2<String, JSONObject>, String, TimeWindow> {
        @Override
        public void apply(String key, TimeWindow timeWindow, Iterable<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> iterable, Collector<Tuple2<String, JSONObject>> collector) throws Exception {

        }
    }

}
```